# How to pass pdf data from HttpResponse to ResponseEntity in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, inputstream, httpresponse

I have HttpResponse object , which i found from rest call , I want to get pdf content present in HttpResponse object to ResponseEntity object . I have written the below code for conversion. but its creating empty pdf with 33kb size but actual size is 22kb.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getdata" ,produces = "application/pdf" )
public ResponseEntity<?> getAccount() throws Exception {    
        HttpResponse response = getData();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        final InputStream inStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inStream);
        
        String filename = "output.pdf";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(inputStreamResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't read PDF content directly in Java.

You need to use a dedicated library like pdfbox, for example.

You can find a sample code [there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-data-from-pdf-file-and-display-on-console-in-java)

A sample code :

```
File file = new File("D://Sample.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
//Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
//Retrieving text from PDF document
String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
```